# PaddedForm adds an additional padding character

Tags: output-formatting

I would like to get a sequence from  `"01"` to `"10"`. I tried

```
ToString@PaddedForm[#, 1, NumberPadding -> "0"] & /@ Range@10

(*{"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "010"}*)
```

But this returns  `"010"` instead of `"10"`. What am I doing wrong?

And yes, I know I can do

```
StringTake[ToString[PaddedForm[#, 1, NumberPadding -> "0"]], -2] & /@ Range@10

(*{"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10"}*)
```

But this feels like a hack.

Comment: I would it like so `StringJoin@(ToString /@ PadLeft[IntegerDigits[#], 2]) & /@ Range@10`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that PaddedForm pads the possible sign that might occupy an extra space with another zero.

```
PaddedForm[1, 2, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}]
```

001

```
PaddedForm[1, 2, NumberPadding->{"0",""},NumberSigns->{"",""}]
```

01

Comment: Hmm, thanks. A bit shorter form works as well `PaddedForm[#, 2, NumberPadding -> "0", 
   NumberSigns -> {"", ""}] & /@ {1, 10}`

Comment: @Ajasja, Ymareth BTW, you can supply a list of numbers directly to `PaddedForm` and related functions.

Answer (score 9):

This may be what you're looking for.

```
IntegerString[#, 10, 2] & /@ Range[10]
```

> ```
> {"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10"}
> ```

Comment: +1 Yes, love it. But why is `PaddedForm` not working?

Comment: I believe that PaddedForm adds padding to the left/right regardless of what is in the middle